# Fail to import `csv` module when it is embedded in another python file

Tags: python, csv

In a file `readCSV.py`, I write a function `read_file`:

```
import csv
def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f_input:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f_input):
            #do something...
    return data
```

And I use this function in `ipython notebook`:

```
df = readCSV.read_file("f.txt")
```

And I got this error:

```
NameError: global name 'csv' is not defined
```

Could you please tell me why does it happen and how can I solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your file called `read.py` or `readCSV.py`?

Comment: You may not be importing the file you think you are. `print(readCSV.__file__)` to see what you got.

Comment: @cdarke Sorry, it should be `readCSV.py`

Comment: @tdelaney I got `readCSV.py`

Comment: Did you modify the file `readCSV.py` after you imported it in your notebook? Did you add the `import csv` later? Try a kernel restart and import again?

Comment: @MikeMüller success after restart the kernel. Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Nice. Made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports a module only once. Therefore, if you change the content of a module after you imported it in a notebook you will not see the changes. So adding `import csv` to your already imported module will produce this error. Simplest solution: restart the kernel.

A better solution would be to use [autoreload](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload). This:

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

would automatically re-load all imported modules if they changed when executing a cell.